# Is it possible to configure an OCR library for only a custom set of input characters?

Tags: android, ocr

I'm toying with the idea of creating an Android app to identify a set of given characters [let's say just A,E,I,O,U] and nothing more, in a given image. Is there a way I make use of the existing open-sourced OCR library and configure the language/character inputs as I'd like to have it? If yes, how can I do it?

Your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First let me tell you that using OCR in Android (or general) is no easy feat with OpenSource libraries.

The best library (believe me, I tried severals) you can found is [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) with its [Android port](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two)

With tesseract you can 'train' (as they say) it to recognize custom fonts or particular ones, you can set the main lenguage to process the image, and you can also use:

`engine.setVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "aeiou");`

So it only recognize certain characters. So There you go, do your research on Tesseract!